# c# wpf MVVM Get ObservableList from ObservableDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm, observablecollection

I had some problems with the speed of my application and did some performance profiling. The result shows that there is a lot of time in my application that is spent with linq queries especially to the ID's of the Models. My idea was to create a observable dictionary with the ID as the key and the model as the Value. This works pretty good and is much faster than the linq queries with

```
.Any(x => x.ID == id)
```

or the linq query with

```
.First(x => x.ID == id)
```

As ObservableDictionary I used this sample

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/

the problem now is that I need to create a ObservableCollection which I can bind to my Views. I tried to expand the ObservableDictionary with a ObservableValue Property but that does not work

```
     public ObservableCollection<TValue> ObservableValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (observableValues == null)
            {
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    if (observableValues == null)
                        observableValues = new ObservableCollection<TValue>(Dictionary.Values);
                }
            }
            return observableValues;
        }
    }
```

When I add a Model to my dictionary or update a model the ObservableCollection which is bound to the Views will not update.

Comment: Off topic editorial: Dictionaries suck, even when observable.  Take that OD impl and throw it in the gotdamn trash basket.  Grab you a shiny new KeyedCollection<K,T> and bolt on INotifyCollectionChanged and salvage whatever INCC impl you can from the OD impl (maybe you shouldn't have thrown it in the trash just yet).  KeyedCollections are an IEnumerable<T>, where T has a property that is the key.  KCs work very well with WPF bindings, which love IE<T>, but which suck with dictionaries, which are IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,T>>.  That KVP wrapping makes things harder than they need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion but i tryed some implementations of a KeyedCollection and decided to switch all Collections / Dictionarys to my custom implementation of a KeyedCollection. The Performance is as fast as with the dictionary but without the using of the KVP's. Heres my observable implementation with some Replace Methods and it worked very fast.

```
public class ObservableKeyedCollection<TKey, TItem> : KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private const string CountString = "Count";
    private readonly Func<TItem, TKey> _getKeyForItemDelegate;

    // Constructor now requires a delegate to get the key from the item
    public ObservableKeyedCollection(Func<TItem, TKey> getKeyForItemDelegate) : base()
    {
        if (getKeyForItemDelegate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Delegate passed can't be null!");

        _getKeyForItemDelegate = getKeyForItemDelegate;
    }

    protected override TKey GetKeyForItem(TItem item)
    {
        return _getKeyForItemDelegate(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to add a new object to the collection, or to replace an existing one if there is 
    /// already an object with the same key in the collection.
    /// </summary>
    public void AddOrReplace(TItem newObject)
    {
        int i = GetItemIndex(newObject);
        if (i != -1)
            SetItem(i, newObject);
        else
            Add(newObject);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Method to replace an existing object in the collection, i.e., an object with the same key. 
    /// An exception is thrown if there is no existing object with the same key.
    /// </summary>
    public void Replace(TItem newObject)
    {
        int i = GetItemIndex(newObject);
        if (i != -1)
            SetItem(i, newObject);
        else
            throw new Exception("Object to be replaced not found in collection.");
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Method to get the index into the List{} in the base collection for an item that may or may 
    /// not be in the collection. Returns -1 if not found.
    /// </summary>
    private int GetItemIndex(TItem itemToFind)
    {
        TKey keyToFind = GetKeyForItem(itemToFind);
        if (this.Contains(keyToFind))
            return this.IndexOf(this[keyToFind]);
        else return -1;
    }

    // Overrides a lot of methods that can cause collection change
    protected override void SetItem(int index, TItem item)
    {
        var oldItem = base[index];
        base.SetItem(index, item);
        OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, item, oldItem);
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, TItem item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item);
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        base.ClearItems();
        OnCollectionChanged();
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        TItem item = this[index];
        base.RemoveItem(index);
        OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item);
    }

    private bool _deferNotifyCollectionChanged = false;
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TItem> items)
    {
        _deferNotifyCollectionChanged = true;
        foreach (var item in items)
            Add(item);
        _deferNotifyCollectionChanged = false;

        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_deferNotifyCollectionChanged)
            return;

        if (CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, e);
    }

    #region INotifyCollectionChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(CountString);
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    private void OnCollectionChanged()
    {
        if (_deferNotifyCollectionChanged)
            return;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }


    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, TItem changedItem)
    {
        if (_deferNotifyCollectionChanged)
            return;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, changedItem));
    }


    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, TItem newItem, TItem oldItem)
    {
        if (_deferNotifyCollectionChanged)
            return;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItem, oldItem));
    }


    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, IList newItems)
    {
        if (_deferNotifyCollectionChanged)
            return;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItems));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of is to keep in your `ObservableDictionnary` an `ObservableCollection` containing all the values of the dictionnary.

You then have to change your class so that when you insert/update/delete a value in the dicionnary, it does the same in the `ObservableCollection` thus, firing the event to update the view.